# datamin and datamax in Viewer() did not work

Tags: python, fipy

I used the above code in the fipy, but the range of color bar is always not changed( always showed  [-1,1]).
My version is  Python 3.6.7 and matlablib 3.1.1.

```
#create a viewer to see the results
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        viewer = Viewer(vars=psi, datamin=-0.01, datamax=0)
        viewer.plot()
```

I tried the following:
1, I changed the code in "C:\Users\Lenovo\fipy\examples\diffusion", for example, changed "datamin=-0.01, datamax=0". is not work.
2, directly used "MatplotlibViewer". is not work.
3, used “GnuplotViewer". Can not install in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is a bug in FiPy such that the `datamin` and `datamax` values are not used when rendering the colorbar for 2D plots. The issue is described [here](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/662) and [here](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/663). There is a workaround, however.

This example renders a plot that should have three cells with max value above 3, but is cut off at 3.

```
from fipy import Grid2D, CellVariable, Viewer
from fipy.viewers.matplotlibViewer.matplotlibViewer import _ColorBar

m = Grid2D(nx=3, ny=3)

v = CellVariable(mesh=m)
v[:] = m.x * m.y

vi = Viewer(v, colorbar=None, datamin=0.0, datamax=3.0)
vi.colorbar = _ColorBar(viewer=vi, vmin=0.0, vmax=3.0)

vi.plot()

input('stopped')
```

It's necessary to use the `datamin` and `datamax` arguments and set the `colorbar` argument to `None` and then add the colorbar with the correct `vmin` and `vmax` values as these aren't being set correctly in FiPy.

Comment: @Liu: If this answers your question, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)